# How to dynamically adds CSP nonce attributes for inline scripts/styles with AWS Lambda + CloudFront + S3 setup?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, content-security-policy

According to [official AWS documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/adding-http-security-headers-using-lambdaedge-and-amazon-cloudfront/), I can add static `Content-Security-Policy` headers via AWS Lambda. But I'd like to know if there's a way to add dynamic `nonce-<base64-value>` and change every time the viewer refresh the page?

This is how I add CSP headers via Node.js:

```
'use strict';
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    //Get contents of response
    const response = event.Records[0].cf.response;
    const headers = response.headers;

    //Set new headers 
    headers['content-security-policy'] = [{key: 'Content-Security-Policy', value: "default-src 'none'; img-src 'self'; script-src 'self'; style-src 'self'; object-src 'none'"}]; 

    //Return modified response
    callback(null, response);
};
```

But how can I get the response body from Lambda?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone finding this questions years later. This is currently not supported and there are some workarounds. I created an issue on the official cloudfront function repo:
https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-cloudfront-functions/issues/3

In my issue I also mention some workarounds.

Answer (score -1):

As I know there is a checkbox in CloudFront configuration with "Send response body to lambda"

Comment: There's only a "Send _request_ body to lambda" to help manage POST requests. There is no access to the response body on Viewer or Origin response